# How to calculate the value of a previous row from the count of another column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to create an additional column which calculates the value of a row from count column with its predecessor row from the sum column. Below is the query. I tried using ROLLUP but it does not serve the purpose.

```
select to_char(register_date,'YYYY-MM') as "registered_in_month"
      ,count(*) as Total_count
from CMSS.USERS_PROFILE a
where a.pcms_db != '*' 
group by (to_char(register_date,'YYYY-MM'))
order by to_char(register_date,'YYYY-MM')
```

This is what i get

```
registered_in_month   TOTAL_COUNT
-------------------------------------
2005-01                1
2005-02                3
2005-04                8
2005-06                4
```

But what I would like to display is below, including the months which have count as 0

```
registered_in_month   TOTAL_COUNT  SUM
------------------------------------------
2005-01                1           1
2005-02                3           4
2005-03                0           4
2005-04                8           12
2005-05                0           12
2005-06                4           16
```

Comment: There's two parts to this - 1) Aggregating by month, and including missing months (a Calendar Table would help you immensely) 2) The running sum (which should have multiple examples on this site).

Comment: Agreed. but the problem is i am not sure how sum it with the rows got as a result from count(*). It would be great if someone can show that

Comment: The question i have posted is completely different from the you have mentioned as a duplicate. can anyone please help ASAP. 
I have not got so much knowledge about sql so i'd appreciate if you consider that while answering

Comment: Maybe (vote retracted) - however, you _can_ reduce the problem to that point, by doing things like aggregation in a subquery or CTE (which would _also_ be part of a duplicate question).

Comment: And by the way i have solved one part of the question but i still need help to calculate the row from count(*) to previous row of the resultant column

Answer (score 2):

To include missing months in your result, first you need to have complete list of months. To do that you should find the earliest and latest month and then use heirarchial
query to generate the complete list.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf13f/6)

```
with x(min_date, max_date) as (
  select min(trunc(register_date,'month')),
         max(trunc(register_date,'month'))
  from users_profile
  )
select add_months(min_date,level-1)
from x
connect by add_months(min_date,level-1) <= max_date;
```

Once you have all the months, you can outer join it to your table. To get the cumulative sum, simply add up the count using SUM as analytical function.

```
with x(min_date, max_date) as (
  select min(trunc(register_date,'month')),
         max(trunc(register_date,'month'))
  from users_profile
  ),
y(all_months) as (
  select add_months(min_date,level-1)
  from x
  connect by add_months(min_date,level-1) <= max_date
  )
select to_char(a.all_months,'yyyy-mm') registered_in_month,
       count(b.register_date) total_count,
       sum(count(b.register_date)) over (order by a.all_months) "sum"
from y a left outer join users_profile b
         on a.all_months = trunc(b.register_date,'month')
group by a.all_months
order by a.all_months;
```

Output:

```
| REGISTERED_IN_MONTH | TOTAL_COUNT | SUM |
|---------------------|-------------|-----|
|             2005-01 |           1 |   1 |
|             2005-02 |           3 |   4 |
|             2005-03 |           0 |   4 |
|             2005-04 |           8 |  12 |
|             2005-05 |           0 |  12 |
|             2005-06 |           4 |  16 |
```

Comment: #ERROR!